# Clicking on SVG element stops key events from firing

Tags: javascript, svg, events

I am making a game using PIXI for graphics, and Mithril for some UI elements. I create event listeners for the various inputs (WASD for movement, mouse clicks for action). I am rendering an SVG as part of the UI (with an <object> tag), and when I click that SVG, there must be some "refocusing" in the browser, as the key inputs stop firing events. In particular, I cannot even use the key that is supposed to toggle the SVG on/off!

I cannot simply turn off interaction with the element, as I need to be able to attach event listeners to certain elements within the SVG. How do I fix this "refocusing" behaviour? Strangely enough, I can't get an onclick to fire when clicking the svg either (after passing an onclick function to the <object> element).

Answer (score 1):

Your SVG being loaded in an <object> element just like in an <iframe>, has its own Document that is sand-boxed from the owner Document.

Events happening in one context won't be visible to the other one. That's on purpose, you wouldn't want a random ad on a page to be able to read everything that is typed in its embeder, and similarily in the other way.

So here the easy solution is to append your SVG as an inline element inside the main Document directly:

```js
onkeydown = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  console.log( "pressed", evt.key );
}
```

```html
Press any key or click on the rect<br>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100">
  <rect fill="green" width="100" height="100"/>
  <script>
    document.querySelector("rect")
      .addEventListener("click", (evt) =>
        evt.target.setAttribute("fill", "#" + ((Math.random()*0xFFFFF)|0) )
      );
  </script>
</svg>
```

---

If your svg image and your Document share the same origin, you could access the <object>'s `.contentDocument` and attach events there even from the main doc.

```
document.querySelector("object").addEventListener("load", (evt) => {
  const doc = evt.target.contentDocument;
  // add your event here
  doc.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
});
```

[Outsourced example](https://jsfiddle.net/d32o1ajz/) because StackSnippet's null-origin iframes can't be Same-Origin...

---

For cross-origin documents, a **more complicated** way would be to create a hub between both contexts, and to let the other side know when an event occurred.

There is a [proposal going which should allow this](https://github.com/WICG/input-for-workers), though it hasn't been updated since a long time, and it's rather aiming OffscreenCanvas in Web-Workers as a use-case. But the way it was going at the [last update](https://github.com/WICG/input-for-workers/pull/8) could let hope this situation could also be handled.

[I wrote an hackish implementation](https://github.com/Kaiido/EventPort.js) loosely based on that last proposal, here is an example of use:

```js
const svg_content = `
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect fill="green" width="100" height="100"/>
  <!-- load the script from both sides
    note that here we load the "cross-origin" version,
    because StackSnippet's null-origined iframes make this object cross-origin...
  -->
  <script href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Kaiido/EventPort.js@cross-origin/EventPort.js"/>
  <script>
    document.querySelector("rect")
      .addEventListener("click", (evt) =>
        evt.target.setAttribute("fill", "#" + ((Math.random()*0xFFFFF)|0) )
      );
    // "parent" will listen to Events firing on "window"
    const eventPort = window.createEventPort();
    parent.postMessage( eventPort, "*", [eventPort] );
  <\/script>
</svg>
`;

document.querySelector("object")
  .data = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ svg_content ], { type: "image/svg+xml" } ) );

// we wait for the SVG document to send our EventPort object
window.addEventListener("message", (evt) => {
  const eventPort = evt.eventPorts[ 0 ];
  // now we can listen to the events occuring there
  eventPort.addEventListener( "keydown", (evt) => {
    console.log( "pressed in svg document", evt.key );
  });
  eventPort.addEventListener( "click", (evt) => {
    console.log( "clicked in svg document" );
  });
});
addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
  console.log( "pressed in main document", evt.key );
})
```

```html
<!-- load the script from both sides -->
<script src="https://kaiido.github.io/EventPort.js/EventPort.js"></script>
Press any key or click on the rect<br>
<object></object>
```

But really, my script is hackish, I only wrote that as a proof of concept to help better design a possible API, and because it overwrites a lot of globals it can very well break other stuff on your page.
So if you can, **go the easy way: inline your svg**.

Comment: Because I am using Mithril to manage UI state, I don't want to inline much in the main document. Thanks to your answer I have managed to partially solve my problems by calling document.body.focus() in a click event listener on the svg element, which causes the focus to immediately flip back on clicking, however I will have to register similar handlers for every event which changes focus. Do you know whether it is possible to prevent the focus change in the first place but still allow handling of clicks and so on? I suppose not, in which case, do you know a simpler way to do what I described?

Comment: Do you absolutely need the click event on the svg to be on the filled part of elements or anywhere in the svg would be ok? If the latter, then use an <img> to render your svg.

Comment: I am using an svg specifically because I wanted to be able to attach different listeners to different parts of the image.

Comment: You still have the [<map>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) element, otherwise, I think I gave all I could think of in my answer.